# The whole app shifts towards left when Internet Explorer is not expanded to its whole width and length

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have reduced the length and width of IE browser window. The app loads properly for the first time. Now I have a form which opens on the click of a button on my Homepage. In the form, if I leave a field invalid and I click on save, the code is written such that if there is any field invalid, it will focus on the invalid field. So, with IE10 browser window small, when I leave a field in this form invalid and click on save, the whole app shifts towards left inlcuding the form and the fields inside the form. I have no clue why this is happening. I am using the following code to focus on the invalid field,

```
child.getEl().dom.scrollIntoView();
```

I am aware that there is some bug with scrollIntoView when using IE browser. Can someone suggest me the alternative to scrollIntoView()? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the foloowing instead of scrollIntoView(), 
1) field.getEl().focus() to focus on invalid field
2) panel.body.el.scrollTo('Top',0,true) to scroll the form to the top every time we open it